# Java differentiating between four similar strings

Tags: java

This particular class I'm coding gets its input from a text file, obtained from OCR software used on a survey diagram. The input data is fairly dirty and the purpose of this class is to clean it and finally assign it to an array of objects which will then be used by other classes.

Now to my question: I need to be able to recognize 4 different types of character sets. If my code finds these at the start of the line, it knows that the specific line needs to be included into the String[] array I want to work with. The four sets it needs to recognize are in the formats "AZ", "A1Z1", "ZA1" "Z1A" (can be any alphabetic character and 1-9 number)

```
String typeOne = "AZ1063.662521446A63764.73138685.41"
```

Which is separated into 
    "AZ", 1063.66, "2521446", "A", 63764.73, 138675.41

```
String typeTwo = "A1Z11063.662521446A63764.73138685.41"
```

Which is separated into "A1Z1", 1063.66, "2521446", "A1", 63764.73, 138675.41

```
String typeThree "ZA111063.662521446A63764.73138685.41"
```

Which is separated into: "ZA1", 1063.66, "2521446", "Z", 63764.73, 138675.41

```
String typeFour "Z1A1063.662521446A63764.73138685.41"
```

Which is separated into "Z1A", 1063.66, "2521446", "Z1", 63764.73, 138675.41

Now the problem is that every test I've managed to devise so far, cannot differentiate between typeOne and typeThree, since the third character in both strings is always a number and these Strings never have a fixed length. I'm genuinely curious as to how I can detect a difference between the two types.

Edit: For clarifications sake - the second set of data I want, after the initial 'identifier' (AZ1) will later be converted to double (1063.66). This means that I need to recognize a case of AZ1, so the 1 does not get added to the double (11063.66). While this would be relatively simple if the different parts that make up the string had fixed lengths, they do not, therefore the problem.

Comment: You won't be able to decide if it's type 1 or type 3 when the input String has a variable size. The only way is to set the type of a String like "AZ1" always type three.

Comment: Wait a second, if any alphabetic character and any number is valid, why exactly is type 3 not a subset of type 1? From your example I get that the third character being a number does not mean it's not type 1. Can you describe me in human words how a human would separate those two? Why your typeOne example is not a type 3?

Comment: @Aziuth This is exactly what's throwing me off, there is no way to differentiate between strings with exactly the same format `[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]*` They follow the same expression so surely there cannot be a way to differentiate, unless non-determinism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not quite sure if I understood the problem correcly, but have you tried parsing it backwards?

If you start from the end, you have 
6.2 Digits float,
5.2 Digits float,
Letter
6 Digits
4.2 Digits float
- rest (your separation).

if you dont have any fixed length, the input does not seem to be separable

Comment: This is actually actually a brilliant idea! I can start separating the String from the back forwards and whatever is left over will be the identifier. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, why are you not using a regular expression match? If in case 3 the initial letter is equal to the 18th (as it seems from the example you're giving) this is the expression

```
s.matches("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9].*") && (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(18));
```

If the case3 string is longer than case1 (as it seems from the example you're giving) this is the expression

```
s3.matches("^[A-Z]{2}.{34}");
```

Comment: I am using regular expression at the moment, but as the strings never have a fixed length, I will be unable to ascertain where the character it needs to match to is located at.

Comment: Just to complete the answer: if the first character is equal to the one at the nth position, then you can look for the index of the match until that caracter and compare the first and the nth.

Comment: That is indeed what I understood you were saying, but my point still stands. I still have no way of knowing if the character following "AZ" at the start of the string is part of the next value or should instead be part of "AZ1". Thankfully I did manage to solve this issue, by comparing characters from the previous and next string inputs, since the data is supposed to be sequential. Thank you for the attempted help, though!

Comment: I'm glad you solved. Can I ask you, just for the sake of it, if this would work? `System.out.println("s3 " +( s3.charAt(0) == s3.split("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")[1].charAt(0)));` This outputs true, which means that the first character and the first character after the numbers are equal. [And here is the link of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/uY4uD9/1)

Comment: Your logic is sound, yes, but I still have no way of knowing if the first number after the first set of letters is part of the string or the following float. Now that I've spent several hours on this problem, I have come to the conclusion that it is, quite literally, impossible to do what I wanted to do simply using the single string. But when you consider the input from the strings before and after it, the process is relatively simple. In any

Answer (score -2):

You can use the method startsWith() like;

```
String str = "ZA111063.662521446A63764.73138685.41";
if(str.startsWith("AZ")){
  ... do something;
}
```

The second line will return true;

Comment: This will not work, `(can be any alphabetic character and 1-9 number)`, means that the strings don't follow the scheme of having `ZA1` all the time, they can have different beginnings matching `[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]*`